# How other users can view the web content created by Admin liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I have created the web content as Admin.
Now I want this web content viewable by other users as well.
I have set view permissions for user for that web content also but its not visible to users.

Comment: Have you enabled workflow for the content. After you create the content see what is the status of the content in web content listing in the control panel. Is it "Approved" or "Pending". If its pending it is in workflow and it has to approved by user with appropriate role.

Comment: Status is Approved.. Once you published the web content its in Approved status..In control panel, in list of web content there is an Action tab -> Permissions -> there also I have added view permissions to user, guest, power user.. then also I cant see the web content as User.